What is the best way to initalize 2D std::array along with its rows and cols?
I want to find the best possible way of initializing std:array in the below configuration (a better way would be able to use the cols and rows variables while declaring the array size):
class Engine {
protected:
    const int rows = 30;
    const int cols = 100;
    std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 30> arr;
}

How do initialize it properly? I mean, my rows and cols are going to be const, so:

do I just make rows and cols be static const and then somehow initialize arr at compile time with those variables?
is initializing arr this way ok, or is it tragic?

Anyway, I want to find the best possible (ie golden standard) way of initializing it, while I know how my array will look like at compile time.

What are the values you want to initialize it with?

No need of member, so static const is better. Drop them is an alternative, dimension can be retrieved directly by arr.size() or arr[0].size()...

There is no need to use const in class members - it states syntactic constant, but a better way to do this is to declare then non-const and just don't provide setters for them. That way you let compiler generate a bunch of thing for you

Why not just create a 1D array and then have accessor functions that work out the 2D dimensions (which is fairly trivial - y*width+x)? Usually works out to be more efficient.

@JesperJuhl They are std::arrays though so I'm not sure you could do it more efficiently by using the y*width+x version that one often uses with vectors to get a 2D interface

@floatfoo -- if they're not const they can't be used as dimensions for std::array.

@zkoza the size of std::array must be determined at compile time (and it seems to fit the OP's needs).


Anyway, I want to find the best possible (ie golden standard) way of initializing it, while I know how my array will look like at compile time.

You can use static constexpr as shown below:
class Engine {
protected:
    static constexpr std::size_t rows = 30;
    static constexpr std::size_t cols = 100;
    std::array<std::array<int, cols>, rows> arr;
};


It would seem reasonable to make these template parameters.
template <std::size_t rows = 30, std::size_t cols = 100>
class Engine {
protected:   
    std::array<std::array<int, cols>, rows> arr;
};

